# Database Mirroring and Logshipping

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, mirroring, log-shipping

I have setup both mirroring and and log shipping on 8 databases of about 10 GB each size on same instance, but now when I want to mirror another database it very long to display the Database Properties page. Any suggestion for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using "ALTER DATABASE [dbname] SET SAFETY FULL" as that will cause the databases to update syncronized (e.g. your transaction will not complete until commited on both database servers).

If you have high latency between the servers, you will get a large performance penalty.

You could use "ALTER DATABASE [dbname] SET SAFETY OFF" which will not give you full mirroring (the slave can fall behind, and you have to manually fail-over), but you will not get a performance penalty.

See BOL for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a trace and see what is going on when the GUI makes the call to SQL.

I had a similar problem with a database that was moved from 2000 to 2005, but it eventually cleared up on it's own.